# How do I get another counter?

Tags: c++, swap, masm, 32-bit, bubble-sort

I'm trying to compare bubble sort between C++ and MASM. I've got the C++ working without issue. With MASM, however, I need another counter in loopSwap, but I don't know how to go about it.

I know that if I push a register, it would have to be before the comparison but if the comparison jump is met, I wouldn't be able to pop the same register.

Any help is appreciated!

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int deepBlueDecend(int* num, int size);
int deepBlueAscend(int* num, int size);
//int setArray(int* num, int size);

extern"C"
{
    int KasparovAscend(int *, int);
    int KasparovDecend(int *, int);
}

int main()
{
    int ascOrDec = 2, size = 0;
    cout << "How big do you want the array to be sorted? ";
    cin >> size;

    int* myArray = 0;
    myArray = new int[size];
    int* asmArray = 0;
    asmArray = new int[size];

    srand((unsigned)time(0));                       // gets actually random numbers somehow
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  //populates the arrays with random numbers
    {
        myArray[i] = rand();
        asmArray[i] = myArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << asmArray[i] << " "; //displays asmArray[]
    cout << endl;

    while (ascOrDec < 0 || ascOrDec > 1)            //test if ascending or decending has been chosen
    {
        cout << "Ascending (0) or decending(1)? ";
        cin >> ascOrDec;        
        if (ascOrDec == 0 || ascOrDec == 1)
            break;
    }

    cout << endl;
    if (ascOrDec == 0)
    {
        KasparovAscend(asmArray, size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << asmArray[i] << " "; //to see if anything changed in the assembly sort
        cout << endl;

        clock_t startTime = clock();
        deepBlueAscend(myArray, size);
        clock_t endTime = clock();
        clock_t clockTicksTaken = endTime - startTime;
        double timeInSeconds = clockTicksTaken / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << myArray[i] << " "; //to see if anything changed in the C++ sort
        cout << "\nTime Taken for c++: " << clockTicksTaken << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        clock_t startTime = clock();
        deepBlueDecend(myArray, size);
        clock_t endTime = clock();
        clock_t clockTicksTaken = endTime - startTime;
        double timeInSeconds = clockTicksTaken / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "\nTime Taken for c++: " << clockTicksTaken << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int deepBlueAscend(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i, j, flag = 1;    // set flag to 1 to start first pass
    int temp;             // holding variable

    for (i = 1; (i <= size) && flag; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])      // ascending order <
            {
                temp = arr[j];             // swap elements
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1;               // indicates that a swap occurred.
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int deepBlueDecend(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i, j, flag = 1;    // set flag to 1 to start first pass
    int temp;             // holding variable

    for (i = 1; (i <= size) && flag == 1; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] > arr[j])      // decending order  >
            {
                temp = arr[j];             // swap elements
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1;               // indicates that a swap occurred.
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and MASM code:

```
.686
.model flat
.code

_help PROC ; named _test because C automaticedxly prepends an underscode, it is needed to interoperate
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp ; stack pointer to ebp

    mov ebx, [ebp+8] ; address of first array element
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; number of elements in array
    mov ebp, ecx
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, 0
    push edi    ;save this
    push ebx    ;save this

    mov edi, ebx    ;make a copy of first element in array
    add edi, 4      ;move 4 to find second element

    mov edx, [ebx]  ;move first element into edx
    mov eax, [edi]  ;move second element into eax


LoopTraverse:
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx, 0
    je AllDone

                    ;set counter in loopSwap to be 0 when first entered

    LoopSwap:
        inc ebp             ;increment
        cmp ecx, eax        ;compares counter to number of elements
        je LoopTraverse 

        cmp edx, eax        ;comparing the two values
        jg NextElements

        push ecx            ;stores eax so it can be used for later
        push edx            ;stores edx so it can be used later

        xchg ebx, edi           ;trade the two elements
        mov ecx, edi
        mov edx, ebx
        xchg [ebp+eax], edx
        xchg [ebp], ecx

        pop edx
        pop ecx

NextElements:
        add edi, 4              ;finds next 
        add ebx, 4              ;finds second element
        mov eax, [edi]
        mov edx, [ebx]



allDone:

    mov eax, ebp
    pop edi
    pop edx
    pop ebp;
    ret
_help ENDP

END
```

Comment: Among other things, appears the epilogue code is wrong. You POP things off in the wrong order. At a minimum remove `xor ebp, ebp` `pop edi` `pop ebx` `pop ebp` and replace it with `pop ebx` `pop edi` `mov esp, ebp` `pop ebp` . You must pop things off in the REVERSE order they were originally pushed.

Comment: I may be seeing things wrong but this looks like it could obliterate the stack including the return address `mov [ebp+eax*4], edi` `mov [ebp+eax*4+1], ebx` . I don't think this code is what you were looking to do. I recommend you step through with a debugger.

Comment: How do I look for what you're mentioning in the debugger?

Comment: Michael, if you're still around, I've changed my MASM code a bit, still incomplete, but it correctly finds the next elements in the array, but now I'm having trouble finding a way to count the number of loops made in loopSwap. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to begin by counting how many pushes you have as compared to how many pops you have.  There are other things about it that look obviously wrong but this is the primary reason it's crashing.  Remember that when it hits the `RET` it's using the next value on the stack as the return address.  Mismatched `PUSH` and `POP` will leave you in the wrong spot since you don't preserve `ESP`

Comment: I stopped the crashing issue, I guess I should edit that out. Thanks though!

Comment: Changing the code with bug fixes the way you are makes this question very hard to track. You've replaced the original code with one set of problems with new code for a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do ***not*** use `ebp` as a variable.
2. After `mov ebp,esp` do `sub esp, 4` to make room in the stack for one more loop counter.
3. Address your new loop counter at `[ebp-4]`.
4. Since you are not allowed to use `ebp` as a variable, you are going to need one more stack variable; so, instead of `sub esp, 4` do `sub esp, 8` and your second stack variable is at `[ebp-8]`.

See [Wikibooks - x86 Disassembly/Functions and Stack Frames](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames)

Comment: Let me get this straight. I can use [ebp-4] and [ebp-8] as their own variable?

Comment: Yes, you can use negative offsets from `ebp` as local variables, provided that you allocate stack for them first, by subtracting bytes from `sp`. It's that simple.  That's where compilers create their local variables.  And that's where humans usually create them too, in the rare event that a human is writing a function so complex that it needs more local variables than there are registers.

Comment: When I try using
 
mov [ebp - 4n]

 I get "A2070: invalid instruction operands" error. How do I use [ebp - 4] like how you describe?

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind by doing `[ebp - 4n]`.  I did not speak of any `4n`. You are already using `[ebp + 4]`, so what is so hard about using `[ebp - 4]`?

Comment: I'm using n as a place holder for the number of bytes to be subtracted. But never mind that... when I do: `mov [ebp - 4], 1` I get an "invalid instruction operands. However, `mov [ebp - 4], ecx` worked. But if I want to use `[ebp - 4]` as a counter, wouldn't I do `sub [ebp - 4], 1`? I get the same error as moving a number into that location.

Comment: Yes, the instruction set has some peculiarities and some limitations.  Not all addressing modes are valid with all instructions both as source and as destination.  I do not remember all the limitations by heart any more, (I used to,) but if I am to believe your observations, it appears that you have to temporarily use a register, like `mov eax, 1` and then `mov [ebp - 4], eax`.

Comment: Okay! I got it to work the way I want it to! Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you help me with swapping elements in memory? I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: `mov eax, [m1]` `mov ebx, [m2]` `mov [m1], ebx` `mov [m2], eax`

Comment: That's what I've got, but when it comes to get the next element, `[m2]` won't change and will throw the program off.
`NextElements:
  add edi, 4     ;finds next 
  mov eax, [edi]

  add ebx, 4    ;finds second element
  mov edx, [ebx]`

`edx` will not move to the next array element.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you.  Perhaps post a new question with only the relevant code, and explain precisely what is happening and precisely what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: I posted another question. Thanks for your patience! I appreciate it.