# Assembly: Stack Parameters instead of Registers

Tags: assembly, parameters, stack, masm, irvine32

I've come across an issue in MASM assembly. I'm having trouble understanding how to use stack parameters instead of registers.

I came up with a silly "program" to help me better understand the concepts.

If you would, write a program to prompt the user for 5 integers, 
    and then display them back to the user.

I've created sort of a template for you to use if you wish...

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
count = 5
scores DWORD count DUP(0)
prompt BYTE "Please type an integer score: ", 0
.code

GetScores PROTO, dwArray:PTR DWORD, arraySize : DWORD

main PROC
exit
main ENDP

GetScores PROC, dwArray:PTR DWORD, arraySize : DWORD

ret
GetScores ENDP

END main
```

How are stack parameters used instead of registers in the context of reading in data, saving data, and sending out data? What I mean is the type of stuff that could be shown by answering the question that I propose above.

Comment: Oh, it is so kind of you that you created sort of a template for us to use.  (If we wish.)  Now, what is your question?  I don't suppose you want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: @MikeNakis My question is how are stack parameters used instead of registers in the context of reading in data, saving data, and sending out data, you know, the type of stuff that could be shown by answering the question that I MADE UP. I doubt any professor in the world would give such an easy assignment.

Comment: @MikeNakis Any suggestions?

Comment: The way stackoverflow works is that you present your non-working code, you explain what you expected it to do and what it does instead, and we provide suggestions or even solutions.  But you have to give it an honest try first.  If you want to see how it is done, it is completely counter-productive *for you* to be posting questions on stackoverflow and *for us* to be answering.  To see how it is done, look for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146282/how-do-i-get-another-counter/34166184#34166184

Comment: @MikeNakis I have edited my question to show my attempt, with a few questions I still have, could you give it a look over?

Comment: Good, that's better.  Here is how to use PROTO, right from the official source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/73407

Answer (score 1):

I have never actually used `PROTO` and `INVOKE`, but the general idea is that `PROTO` is a directive (it does not generate any code) which tells the assembler that you have a function, and the number of parameters that it expects, and the type of each parameter, so that later you can use `INVOKE` to call your function, specifying the parameters inline, like this:

```
INVOKE GetScores scores, count
```

<sup>(this might not be entirely accurate, you may need to say `OFFSET scores`, I don't know and I have no way of trying it.)</sup>

And the assembler will actually emit the following instructions:

```
push OFFSET scores
push count
call GetScores
```

Then, by using `PROC` in your function, you can access these parameters simply as `scores` and as `count` instead of as `[ebp + 8]` and `[ebp + 12]`.

Within your function you can immediately load `scores` and `count` into registers to work with them, as you do in the code that you posted.  It would be silly to keep  reloading `esi` from `scores` in each iteration of your loop.

However, if you were writing a much more complicated function, you would run out of registers, so you would have to save `esi` into `scores` in order to use `esi` for something else, and then reload it from `scores`. You would have to do the same if your `ReadInt` function was making use of ("corrupting") `esi`.

Comment: Aww okay. So a proto is basically an identifier function used to show it's there, very similar to work i've been doing in opengl matter of fact, INVOKE is simply calling a function with parameters, easy enough. I have updated my code after making the changes, but am receiving an error which I have noted. Any ideas?